# how to set new text in JTextField after creation?

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, settext, windowlistener

I have a jTextField , and I set it's value to a certain sum when I create the frame.
Here is the initiation code:

```
totalTextField.setText(
            itemsPriceTextField.getText() +           
                    Float.toString(orderDetails.delivery)
);
```

This textfield should show a sum of items selected by the user.
The selection is done on a different frame,  and both frames are visible / invisible
at a time.
The user can go back and forth and add / remove items.

Now,  every time i set this frame visible again,  I need to reload the value set to that field
(maybe no changes were made,  but if so,  I need to set the new correct sum) .

I'm quite desperate with it.
Can anyone please give me a clue?
Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Are you sure that you are not creating a new frame each time, instead of make it visible?

Comment: Yes I'm sure.. I keep pointers to previous frames and just move back and forth

Comment: whenever you are making the frame visible , aren't you using any listener event as you are making it visible when some operation happens

Comment: if you want to change text while you are in focus to the text field. then you cant do it this way

Answer (score 10):

Before setting the frame visible again,  one should update the fields with the new values / states.
something like:

```
jTextField.setText("put your text here");  
jRadioButton.setSelected(!isSelected());  
.  
/* update all you need */
.  
jFrame.setVisible(true);
```

The frame will come up with the new values / states.

Comment: if you want to change text while you are in focus to the text field. then you cant do it this way.

Answer (score 3):

Add a WindowListener to the frame. Then you can handle the windowActivated event and reset the text of the text field.

See How to [Write Window Listeners](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use a *DocumentListener* triggering the *JTextField public void setText(String t)*

Here an example with *DocumentListener*:

```
public class SetTextInJTextField extends JFrame implements DocumentListener {

JTextField entry;
JTextField entryToSet = new JTextField();

public SetTextInJTextField() {
    createWindow();
    entry.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);
}

private void createWindow() {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Swing Tester");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    createUI(frame);
    frame.setSize(560, 200);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

private void createUI(final JFrame frame) {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    entry = new JTextField();
    entryToSet = new JTextField();

    LayoutManager layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
    panel.setLayout(layout);

    panel.add(this.entry);
    panel.add(entryToSet);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void setTextInTargetTxtField() {
    String s = entry.getText();
    entryToSet.setText(s);
}

// DocumentListener methods
public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
    setTextInTargetTxtField();
}

public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
    setTextInTargetTxtField();
}

public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent ev) {
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
    //creating and showing this application's GUI.
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new SetTextInJTextField().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

---

**inspired from:** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/TextFieldDemoProject/src/components/TextFieldDemo.java

---

**related lesson:** https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html